# Trying to limit the number of shots fired in a space invaders game in python

Tags: python, time

I'm working on a project for my CS101 class, I can't use pygame, but I need to make a space invaders style game. I'm trying to limit the number of shots that the player can have on the screen at once so the player can't just spam space bar to win.

```
import time
import graphics
import random

window_width = 800
num_bad_guys = 10

def create_good_guy(window):
    goodGuy = graphics.Image(graphics.Point (400,500), "scout-idle-16.gif")
    goodGuy.draw(window)
    return goodGuy

def create_bad_guy(window):
    badGuyList = []
    for index in range(num_bad_guys):
        badGuy = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(index*70+50, 70), "enchantress-melee-1.gif")
        badGuyList.append(badGuy)
        badGuy.draw(window)
    return badGuyList

class rect:
    def __init__ (self, pict):
        '''
        pict should be a zelle graphics.image file
        '''
        self.pict = pict
        pass

    def right(self):
        return self.pict.getAnchor().getX() + self.pict.getWidth()/2
    def left(self):
        return self.pict.getAnchor().getX() - self.pict.getWidth()/2
    def top(self):
        return self.pict.getAnchor().getY() - self.pict.getHeight()/2
    def bottom(self):
        return self.pict.getAnchor().getY() + self.pict.getHeight()/2

def overlap(r1,r2):
    '''Overlapping rectangles overlap both horizontally & vertically
    edited from the original to work with the rect class below '''
    hoverlaps = True
    voverlaps = True
    if (r1.left() > r2.right()) or (r1.right() < r2.left()):
        hoverlaps = False
    if (r1.top() > r2.bottom()) or (r1.bottom() < r2.top()):
        voverlaps = False
    return hoverlaps and voverlaps

def event_loop(win, goodGuy, badGuys):
    deltaX = 5
    deltaY = 5
    dX = 0
    dY = 5
    currNumBadGuys = num_bad_guys
    gShotList = []
    bShotList = []
    bShotCount = 0
    score = 0
    scoreText = graphics.Text(graphics.Point(100, 20), "Current Score: %d" %score)
    scoreText.draw(win)
    scoreText.setSize(15)
    while True:
        bShotCount = bShotCount + 1
        goodGuy.move(dX, 0)
        time.sleep(0.03)
        keyPressed = win.checkKey()
        if keyPressed == 'Left':
            dX = -5
        elif keyPressed == 'Right':
            dX = 5
        if goodGuy.getAnchor().getX()-(goodGuy.getWidth()/2)<=0 or \
                goodGuy.getAnchor().getX()+(goodGuy.getWidth()/2)>=window_width:
            dX = -dX
        if keyPressed == 'space':
            goodShot = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(goodGuy.getAnchor().getX(),goodGuy.getAnchor().getY()), 'shot4.gif')
            gShotList.append(goodShot)
            goodShot.draw(win)
        if len(gShotList) != 0:
            for shot in gShotList:
                shot.move(0, -dY)
                gShotRec = rect(shot)
                for guy in badGuys:
                    badGuyRec = rect(guy)
                    if overlap(gShotRec, badGuyRec):
                        shot.undraw()
                        gShotList.remove(shot)
                        guy.undraw()
                        badGuys.remove(guy)
                        currNumBadGuys = currNumBadGuys-1
                        score = score+5
                        scoreText.setText("Current Score: %s" %score)
                        if currNumBadGuys == 0:
                            winning = graphics.Text(graphics.Point(400,300), "You Win!")
                            winning.setSize(25)
                            winning.draw(win)
                            time.sleep(3)
                            return
        if badGuys[0].getAnchor().getX()-(badGuys[0].getWidth()/2)<=0 or \
                badGuys[currNumBadGuys-1].getAnchor().getX()+(badGuys[currNumBadGuys-1].getWidth()/2)>=window_width:
            deltaX = -deltaX
        randomGuy = random.choice(badGuys)
        if bShotCount > 100:
                bShotCount = 0
                badShot = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(randomGuy.getAnchor().getX(), randomGuy.getAnchor().getY()), 'shot5.gif')
                bShotList.append(badShot)
                badShot.draw(win)
        for shot in bShotList:
            shot.move(0, deltaY)
            bShotRec = rect(shot)
            goodGuyRec = rect(goodGuy)
            if overlap(bShotRec, goodGuyRec):
                shot.undraw()
                goodGuy.undraw()
                losing = graphics.Text(graphics.Point(400,300), "You Lose!")
                losing.setSize(25)
                losing.draw(win)
                time.sleep(3)
                return
        for guy in badGuys:
            guy.move(deltaX, 0)

def main():
    win = graphics.GraphWin("Battle Royale", window_width, 600)
    villian = create_bad_guy(win)
    hero = create_good_guy(win)
    event_loop(win, hero, villian)
    win.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of shots in you event handler for the space key.  Before creating a new shot object, check the length of your gShotList.  If the length is less than you MAX_G_SHOTS ( give this constant the value of the max number of shots you want on screen at a time), then add the shot to the list.  Otherwise do nothing.  Now you just need to remove shots from the list when they go off the screen or bit something and die.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you break up the huge event_loop function you have by creating several helper functions on the side.

For your problem, I think that if you test for the number of shots active in `gShotList` before adding a new one, you should be able to limit the shots that can be fired at once.

```
        (...)
        if keyPressed == 'space':
            goodShot = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(goodGuy.getAnchor().getX(),goodGuy.getAnchor().getY()), 'shot4.gif')

        if len(gShotList) < max_simultaneous_shots:
            gShotList.append(goodShot)

        goodShot.draw(win)

        (...)
```

That should probably work as intended.

Please note that `max_simultaneous_shots` must be initialized somewhere (or hard coded for testing the concept).